# MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Attrib on x64 machine failing

Tags: msbuild, 64-bit, msbuildcommunitytasks

I'm having an issue with the Attrib task from the [MSBuild Community Tasks Project](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) when running on a 64 bit build machine.

I've put together this small test project to show what the problem is:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

  <Target Name="PrintProperties">
    <Message Text="MSBuildCommunityTasksPath: $(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildCommunityTasksLib: $(MSBuildCommunityTasksLib)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildNodeCount: $(MSBuildNodeCount)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildExtensionsPath: $(MSBuildExtensionsPath)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildExtensionsPath32: $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildProjectDirectoryNoRoot: $(MSBuildProjectDirectoryNoRoot)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildToolsPath: $(MSBuildToolsPath)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildToolsVersion: $(MSBuildToolsVersion)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildBinPath: $(MSBuildBinPath)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildExtensionsPath: $(MSBuildExtensionsPath)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildProjectDefaultTargets: $(MSBuildProjectDefaultTargets)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildProjectDirectory: $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"/> 
    <Message Text="MSBuildProjectExtension: $(MSBuildProjectExtension)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildProjectFile: $(MSBuildProjectFile)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildProjectFullPath: $(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildProjectName: $(MSBuildProjectName)"/>
    <Message Text="MSBuildStartupDirectory: $(MSBuildStartupDirectory)"/> 
  </Target>

  <Target Name="TestAttrib" DependsOnTargets="PrintProperties">
    <Attrib Files="Test.txt" ReadOnly="false" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

when I attempt to build this project with MSBuild using TestAttrib as the Target I get the following results

C:>msbuild "C:_Source Code\Test.vbproj" /t:TestAttrib
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.30729.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.4016]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 7/09/2009 2:50:12 PM.
Project "C:_Source Code\Test.vbproj" on node 0 (TestAttrib target(s)).
  MSBuildCommunityTasksLib: C:\Program Files\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBu
  ild.Community.Tasks.dll
  MSBuildNodeCount: 1
  MSBuildExtensionsPath: C:\Program Files\MSBuild
  MSBuildExtensionsPath32: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild
  MSBuildProjectDirectoryNoRoot: _Source Code
  MSBuildToolsPath: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5
  MSBuildToolsVersion: 3.5
  MSBuildBinPath: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5
  MSBuildExtensionsPath: C:\Program Files\MSBuild
  MSBuildProjectDefaultTargets: Build
  MSBuildProjectDirectory: C:_Source Code
  MSBuildProjectExtension: .vbproj
  MSBuildProjectFile: Test.vbproj
  MSBuildProjectFullPath: C:_Source Code\Test.vbproj
  MSBuildProjectName: Test
  MSBuildStartupDirectory: C:\
C:_Source Code\Test.vbproj(26,5): error MSB4062: The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Attrib" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, and that the assembly and all its dependencies are available.
Done Building Project "C:_Source Code\Test.vbproj" (TestAttrib target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:_Source Code\Test.vbproj" (TestAttrib target) (1) ->(TestAttrib target) ->  C:_Source Code\Test.vbproj(26,5): error MSB4062: The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Attrib" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, and that the assembly and all its dependencies are available.

```
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.05

Why is the MSBuild searching for the Attrib task in C:\Program Files\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll when I've explicitly imported the tasks using the (MSBuildExtensionsPath32) variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the issue by editing line 6 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"
Originally it was:

```
<MSBuildCommunityTasksPath Condition="'$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
```

and I altered it to:

```
<MSBuildCommunityTasksPath Condition="'$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\MSBuildCommunityTasks</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
```

note the change of $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) to $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)

While this seems to have sorted out my issue for now, I'm not sure why I had to edit the MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets file in the first place - I assumed the installer would have made sure the file was correct. So perhaps editing the MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets file isn't the best idea in the world, so be careful if you decide to follow my lead.

Comment: This is very out of date help. The ms build process has changed since this ticket, best to follow the instructions here https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks

For my project, I used a Build folder in my solution and in the solution I create a MSBuildTasks Folder where I copy the latests MBBuild.Community.Task files in the Zip file release. I then reference the files in my created folder instead

Answer (score 6):

This is obviously far too late an answer, but I thought I would add to this in case anyone else is having this problem. Instead of editing the MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets file, you can just define the MSBuildCommunityTasksPath property in a property group in your build file. For example, I have something like this at the top of my build script:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ToolsDirectory>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\tools</ToolsDirectory>
  <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>$(ToolsDirectory)\MSBuildCommunityTasks</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I then store the MSBuildCommunityTasks folder in a tools directory in source control. It means that other folk can pull out the source and build it straight away without installing anything.

Cheers,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

This is very out of date help. The ms build process has changed since this ticket, best to follow the instructions here https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks

For my project, I used a Build folder in my solution and in the solution I create a MSBuildTasks Folder where I copy the latests MBBuild.Community.Task files in the Zip file release. and put the following lines in my msbuild file

```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>.\MSBuildTasks</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
   </PropertyGroup>  

  <Import Project=".\MSBuildTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
```